# Render Iframe on hover

Tags: html, css, reactjs, hover

How to efficiently render iframe durig hover as shown [here](https://lukesmurray.com/_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Finternal-link-animation.ca16f5926f2b44c69248cfd61a9e3aee.gif&w=1920&q=75)

```html
 <a class="iframe-link" href="https://saheed.codes/uses">Home Page<iframe src="https://saheed.codes/" loading="lazy" style={{width: "100%", height: "600px", border: "0px none"}}></iframe></a>
```

```css
    .iframe-link iframe {
      display: none;
    }
    .iframe-link:hover iframe {
      display: block;
    }
```

I am working with react, and tailwind for styling and would appreciate answers in that direction.

Comment: This question is purely `opinion-based`. You already have a solution. If other methos might be better or not is subjective and opinion-based. Same as all question that ask for the "best way"  or "most efficient" way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using a wrapper for it, you could use `opacity` directly on the iframe. You would already have a reserved space for it and you wouldn't have to use a wrapper. It depends a bit on your use case, your solution is a valid alternative.

```
iframe {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

iframe:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: will be a more solution overall. Because the i frame then will always be there and consume that space. The opacity then will prevent clcik events in that area. means you will not be able to do anything with your mouse in the area there. If you try to select and copy text, you will only reach the iframe.

Comment: it depends on his use case, he didn't give many details

Comment: doesnt depend on the use case. The effect will always be the same with opacity. Also the link he used describted exactly what he wants to do and solves this. He just asking if there is a more effective way now. However this is opinion-based and as such out of scope for SO. Therefor this question should not be answered in the first place. PS: Opacity also will not give the intended animation of the element growing. it will just chaneg the visibility and as said, influence all elements covered up by the iframe at full size.

Comment: @tacoshy is very right, the space would always be there. But i like the transition effect suggested by buondevid but i find it hard to just get this right

Comment: You should then toggle the iframe from `display: block/none` before starting the animation with opacity. That will prevent the iframe to block the space when "hidden"

Comment: @tacoshy please can you explain more clearer what u just said? I'm so lost

Comment: @Saheed tries to combine with `visibility`. In your demo, I see you using `position: absolute`, so, @buondevid mentioned a better way with your

Answer (score 0):

Ended Up doing it this way

```
.iframe-link iframe {
  display: none;
}
.iframe-link:hover iframe {
  -webkit-animation: slow 2s;
       -moz-animation: slow 2s; 
        -ms-animation: slow 2s; 
         -o-animation: slow 2s; 
            animation: slow 2s;
  display: block;
  /* opacity: 1; */

}

@keyframes slow {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```